# else statement not running after firebase query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a web app I've been working on using firebase and I recently hit a block. I am trying to query the contents of a collection and, then run some further code depending on whether or not the query has a successful hit.

Here is my current code:

```
            store
            .collection("users")
            .where("email", "==", email)
            .get()
            .then((docs) => {
                docs.forEach((doc) => {
                    if (doc.exists) {
                        console.log("it exists");
                    } else {
                        console.log("it doesnt exist");
                    }
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.message);
            });
```

The problem I'm having is this: when a document with the email exists in the collection, it logs the appropriate string to the console. However, when it doesn't exist, it totally skips the else statement there, and nothing gets logged at all.

I understand this might just be an error I'm overlooking tho. Is there a better way to perform a check like this with firebase?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would expect if there is an error, that you'd get your log inside of `catch()`.. try putting a log before your if? Maybe log the value of doc?

Comment: I tried that already. Had to clean up the code before posting the question. Logging doc before the if statement returns some complex firebase object when it contains the email in the collection. It's however an empty log when it doesn't. Almost like it doesn't get to that part of the code.

Comment: did you try before the docs.forEach? Maybe docs is not an array on error?

Comment: yup. that was my first syntax after reading the docs. it kept returning 'it doesn't exist' even for emails that were present. The current syntax seems to be the way to go. logging doc.data returns the email, and I'm good with that. its just the else statement that keeps bugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will never reach the else block, since you are checking for existing documents in the collections loop, that has only valid docs.
You should check if the size of the returned collection is bigger than 0.

The final code would be something like this:

```
store
        .collection("users")
        .where("email", "==", email)
        .get()
        .then((docs) => {
          if (docs.size > 0) {
            docs.forEach((doc) => {
                // doc.exists is not necessary
                console.log("it exists");
            });
          } else {
            console.log("it doesnt exist");
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
```

Comment: thanks, leonardo. this works as i intend for it to.